# Code to copy each element of list to another runs without error but does nothing

Tags: list, haskell, printing

I am trying to learn Haskell. In following code, I am trying to copy each element of a list to another through own function and then trying to print new list.

```
orilist =  ["a", "b", "c"]
mylist = []
addfn ss = do   -- trying to add sent string ss to mylist
    let mylist = ss:mylist
    return ()
main = do 
    mapM_ addfn orilist     -- trying to send each element of orilist to addfn
    mapM_ putStrLn mylist   -- trying to print each element of mylist 
    return ()       -- no error but nothing is printed
```

The code runs without any error but nothing is printed. Where is the problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: mylist os a function, the let inside addfn is shadowing not overriding it

Comment: But there is an error if I omit `let`. What is the solution?

Comment: You can't update variables in place in Haskell, as you seem to be assuming. All "variables" are constant and immutable. When you say `myList = []`, that's what it is for the entirety of the program.

Comment: In Haskell everything is immutable, so you can *not* add something to a list.

Comment: I get the idea. Thanks @RobinZigmond and others for your comments.

Comment: You appear to be a Haskell beginner. Before asking questions like this one, I'd recommend reading [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) to completion. This question is about a basic concept in Haskell you're asking about which LYAH covers almost immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
addfn ss = do   -- trying to add sent string ss to mylist
    let mylist = ss:mylist
    return ()
```

This defined a local binding `mylist` to be the infinite list `ss:ss:ss:...`. Then, it's not used, so this definition is irrelevant. Hence, the code is equivalent to:

```
addfn ss = return ()
```

which is a no-op.

Haskell is not an imperative language. You are probably trying to modify the global variable `mylist`, but that's impossible. Once you define `mylist = []`, it will be `[]` forever.

You could do this instead:

```
orilist =  ["a", "b", "c"]

main = do 
    let mylist = orilist
    mapM_ putStrLn mylist   -- trying to print each element of mylist
```

Or even

```
orilist =  ["a", "b", "c"]

main = mapM_ putStrLn orilist
```

---

Another example: suppose we want to start with an empty list and, for 10 times, reverse it and append its length. We can do this as follows, using recursion:

```
doOnce oldList = reverse oldList ++ [length oldList]

newList = go 0 []
   where go 10 list = list
         go n list = go (n+1) (reverse list ++ [length list])
```

This is very inefficient, but I hope but you get the idea.

Comment: How can I create an empty list and then populate it?

Comment: Is it impossible to create an empty list and then populate it? How can I create a list dynamically?

Comment: @mso That's impossible, an empty list will remain empty once created. What you can do is to create an already populated list. Or, at most, to create an empty list, then use that value to compute another list (2), then use that to create yet another list (3), and so on. But at no point you "modify" the original empty list, you create new ones.

Comment: Isn't that computationally expensive? Can you put this in code in your answer above?

Comment: @rnso: no, since functional programming uses data structures that can easily generate copies. For example by prepending the list, you have an *O(1)* operation to create a new list, since you share the "tail" with the old list. Haskell uses for example a *finger tree* as a tree that is good in incremental copies.

Comment: How do I code if I have to read a list of files and add first line of each file to a list? Can I never do this?

Comment: @mso: you definitely can, Haskell is turing complete, so everything you can do with Java, C++, Python, can be done in Haskell as well. In fact it will probably be even easier than doing this in Java, etc.

Comment: @rnso Haskell can be efficient if used right, but if you're a beginner I recommend you disregard efficiency at first and learn the language. In your example, you don't "add the first line to a list", but you "create a list with the first lines of the files inside" instead. Don't think in terms of the state, think in terms of the result. Anyway, I created an (inefficient) example just to show that you can do a "loop modifying a list", without actually modifying anything.

Answer (score 4):

Your `addfn` will not do anything, well it only returns a unit `()`. Indeed, your `addfn` function:

```
addfn ss = do   -- trying to add sent string ss to mylist
    let mylist = ss:mylist
    return ()
```

Is equivalent to:

```
addfn _ = return ()
```

since you never use `mylist`. If you would use `mylist`, it will be an infinite list that contains `[ss, ss, …]`.

In Haskell there are no *assignments*: you do not assign a value to a variable, you *declare* a variable. Once a variable has a value, you can never alter that value. So even if if there was a variable named `mylist` earlier, it would still not use that variable.

After you used `mapM_ addfn orilist`, each `addfn` will have returned `()`, and have not changed the state of anything, hence the list remains empty.

In [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944147/code-to-copy-each-element-of-list-to-another-runs-without-error-but-does-nothing#comment102302396_57944228), you look to read the first line of each file. You can do that, for example by writing a function that reads the first line of a file:

```
import System.IO(IOMode(ReadMode), withFile, hGetLine)

readFirstLine :: FilePath -> IO String
readFirstLine fp = withFile fp ReadMode hGetLine
```

Then we can for example obtain a list of first lines of files with:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    d <- mapM readFirstLine ["foo.txt", "bar.txt"]
    print d
```

Comment: Ok. So, make a function to read one line and then use mapM to get list of lines from different files.

Comment: @mso: indeed, that is the idea behind the `main` here.